# How to create 'endless' tower in Little Big Planet 2?

Tags: little-big-planet-2

In Little Big Planet 2's story, there's a level where you crawl up a tree in a caterpillar.

Here's a video of the level and how it's built: [LittleBigPlanet 2 Sequencer Demo Gamescom 2010](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dAHNIvWehxo)

I'm trying to get my head around this for some hours now. How do I use emitters to emit level-'chunks' at the right position and time to give the illusion of an endless level?

I tried using contact sensors, destroyers and emitters to create a copy of a block at a given position and destroy the latest at the same time, but this seems to create a non-valid recursion and is stopped after about 4 or 5 chunks.

Any hints on this would be awesome.

PS: There are also some other levels by the community which create such an endless 'tunnel'. One such level is "CyberSatra" by "L1ghtmare".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I created a tutorial level that does something similar.  It's very 'terse', since I have to use the SixAxis to enter text, but you should get the idea.

If you do a Text Search for flevine100, you should see a 'random endless scroller tutorial' level.  Go ahead and copy that and read the notes in the level.  It has a very rudimentary endless train of randomly generated blocks.  With a little imagination you can see how this would work in a 'real' level.

Mine uses the random number generator, but a sequencer should work well too.

Here's a brief description of how I did it:

The key is having 2 speeds.. one to let the piece 'catch up' to the train, and one that will move at the speed of the train.  You need a contact sensor to detect when you're touching the train, and when you're not.  This allows your emitters to be less precise when it comes to timing, since the newly generated emitter will travel faster to catch up to the train, but as soon as it touches the train it will change speeds to match the rest of the pieces.  Each block also has a destroyer attached to a tag sensor.  Place a colored tag off the edge of the screen where you want the pieces to disappear.

I created a single circuit board that contained all of this logic, so it was easy to copy the logic to each of the blocks.  The circuit board is given as a prize in the level if you go into play mode.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is so awesome. Your tutorial should have been shipped as a tutorial level.

Comment: Haha - thanks for the kind words.  I'd been trying to figure out how to do this for a week or so and kept getting hosed up by gaps in the blocks or emitters failing to go off.  Once I had them  'catch up', it simplified things quite a bit.  In my experience, the simple solution is usually the right one ;)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit old, but my previous answer was my own 'home grown solution' to the problem.  This video shows a much more elegant way to solve the problem (http://www.youtube.com/user/LBPlanetorials#p/u/29/GEplXDGqtAM)  In addition, the author has a ton of really good v